# jvm method invocation history trace

Tags: java, debugging, jvm

I have a question. Let's say I am running some java core application and I don't really know much about it. The service gets requests and sends back responses. What I want to know is which classes (and methods) are being currently called. Is it possible to put some kind of a time frame and get all java method calls for specific packages (like com.company.xxxx)? Can I use JConsole or any tools available for it?

I appreciate your response

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can issue a [thread dump](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/mandychung/archive/2005/11/thread_dump_and_1.html) using JConsole.

Comment: See also the `jstack` command that comes with many (all?) of the SDKs.

Comment: this would give me a current snap shot but how about 5 min snapshot?

Comment: What operating system are you running on?

Comment: On Unix, send to your Java process the SIGQUIT signal (kill -3) in a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

1. add to `java` command and run

`java -classpath ... -Xdebug -Djava.complier=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5000 ... Main`

2. open `jdb`

```sh
$ jdb -attach localhost:5000
```

3. in `jdb`

```sh
...
Initializing jdb ...
> threads
Group system:
  (java.lang.Thread)0x10bd ...
```

`0x10bd` is the thread id

```sh
trace go methods 0x10bd
```

you will see a line for each enter & exit method